# React chrome full screen delete function F11 and X

Tags: reactjs

I created a web app in react that expands to internal screen after a user 's action with this simple condition:

```js
const onClickButton = () =>{
  if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
      screenfull.request();
    }
}
```

my whole app is now in full screen, but if the 'user presses F11 or the X key in the middle of the web page it comes out of full screen mode without restoring it.

I have tried saving the boolean value of screenfull.isEnabled in a state and with useEffect (with dependency the state screenfull.isEnabled) to make the internal screenfull reset but it does not work.

```js
 const [FullScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(screenfull.isEnabled);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!FullScreen) {
      screenfull.request();
    }
  }, [FullScreen]);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why `screenfull.isEnabled` and not using `true` & `false` instead?

Comment: How can I do a setState if the 'user presses F11 or X in the browser?
With screenfull.isEnabled it initially gives me true, but I expected that once I brought the screen to full screen it would return false

Comment: I don't know the best practice for that but you could use `useInterval` and check every few seconds if the screen is full or not or add a listener/event to check when the value is changed.